# Multiplying metric tensors.

Tags: tensors

Suppose I have the metric $g_{ab}$ in a k-dimensional manifold. Firstly, do metric tensors like this always commute?  Is it always necessarily true that $g^{ab}g_{bc}=\delta^a_c$?
What happens when I multiply metrics like.
$g^{ab}g_{cd}=?$
Finally, is this tensor $g^{cd}(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc})$ always eqal to zero (remember we are in a general k-dimensional manifold.

I cant find any of this explicitly stated in my textbook so any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metric tensors are defined as symmetric bilinear forms, so we can write them as symmetric matrices. As general tensors, metric tensors are not commutative in general (try in dimension $2$ for example to construct two symmetric matrices that do not commute).

Now, if $g^{ab}$
is defined as the inverse matrix of $g_{ab}$
, then $g^{ab}g_{ab}$
is the identity matrix. Hence, $g^{ab}g_{bc}$
is $1$
on the diagonal, $0$
elsewhere (i.e. is $1$
iff $a=c$
).

Finally, one has$$g^{cd}\left(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{bc}\right)=g^{cd}g_{ac}g_{bd}-g^{cd}g_{ad}g_{bc}=g_{a}^{d}g_{bd}-g_{a}^{c}g_{bc}=g_{ab}-g_{ab}=                   0.$$

Comment: However when I fix the indices doesn't that make $g_{ab}$ a number? should it not commute then ? Perhaps I miss phrased my question.. Is it not the case that $g_{ab}g_{dc}=g_{dc}g_{ab}$. Are those not numbers essentially?

Comment: It is the problem of indices abstract notation for tensor : $g_{ab}$ is the tensor (the multilinear map) and $g_{\mu\nu}$ (with greek letters) is the component $\mu\nu$ of your tensor. For example, if $$g_{ab}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix},$$ then $g_{ab}$ is the bilinear form (or the matrix) whereas $g_{21}=-1$ is the component $21$ (read “two - one”) of your matrix.

Comment: whhat about $g_{ab}g^{cd}=?$ can we say something about that?

Comment: Good point here : $g_{ab}g^{cd}$
  is a tensor of type $\left(2,2\right)$
  on your manifold (it is a multilinear map of $2$
  vectors and $2$
  one-forms), and it is not a metric tensor (it is not a matrix, but a table with $4$
  entries). But $g_{ab}g^{bc}$
  for example is a tensor of type $\left(1,1\right)$
  i.e. a linear application (it is still not a metric tensor).